# how to get access elements of a dictionary by its index?

Tags: python, dictionary

how to get access of elements of a dictionary base on its index. for example i have this dictionary with name 'a' :

```
a={'ali':10 , 'reza':19 , 'sara':15}
```

is there any way to get access of first or second or third value of dictionary directly?
i mean, i dont want to use these below codes.

```
a['ali'] or a['reza'] or a['sara']
```

i want to get first/second/third value of above dict directly.
despite i know this is wrong but assume for example i use this code and get access of values by its ***index*** :

```
a[0]  ====>   10  or   a[1]  ====>   19
```

please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: `list(a.values())[0]` or `list(a.values())[1]` or ...

Comment: Your example shows accessing *all* values of the dict. Is that actually what you want in practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the **keys** of the dictionary to a list in order to access by its index. This method has an *`O(n)`* complexity compared to the access by key values directly to the dictionary *(hash table)*, which results in a constant *`O(1)`* time complexity:

```
a={'ali':10 , 'reza':19 , 'sara':15}
print(a[list(a.keys())[0]]) #Here you are getting a list of all keys of the dictionary by calling list(a.keys()), and accessing a specific element of that list with [:] operator
```

**Output:**

```
10
```

Comment: Note that this is very inefficient for most use cases. It scales with both the size of the dict and the number of keys to look up.

Comment: note, `.keys()` is unnecessary

Answer (score -1):

Dictionaries aren't indexed, so no. They're associative, that is, you access elements by their keys. If you want an ordered collection, you need to use a list or a tuple.

Comment: dicts are officially ordered since Python 3.7, so actually yes, you can. See the duplicate.